# auto-login doesnt work with external monitor attached (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, auto-login

I have a laptop with nVidia graphics card and Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I connect it to an external monitor configured to clone the laptop's own screen. Auto-login is enabled (settings>user>auto-login>ON).

Now I'm doing reboot. If the external monitor is NOT attached, auto-login works OK. If external monitor is attached, I'm prompted for the user password. In more details: I see a desktop with panel, starter etc for a moment, then after a few seconds the screen becomes locked and login prompt is displayed. The prompt appears on laptop's screen only, while the external monitor shows background image with "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" label. After entering the password, X-server is restarted and the screens work correctly in clone mode.

It's just a bit annoying to be prompted for a password every time although asked not to do this. Please help!

---

#### Update:

I have studied the problem a bit. It depends on autologin-user-timeout setting. The following tests are all made with connected external monitor.

```
autologin-user-timeout=5
```

- Switch to the other user (not OK):

Expected: login screen will wait 5sec, without user activity will load autologin-user, otherwise will break timeout and allow the other user to login.

Happens really: while selecting the other user and starting to enter the password, timeout is not broken and in 5sec the autologin-user is logged in, not the other user as intended.

- Reboot (OK, more or less):

Expected: in 5sec the autologin-user is logged in.

Happens really: during these 5sec it makes splashes, shows background screen of the other user, probably of the one who was last logged in, but ends with autologin-user logged in.

```
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

- Switch to the other user (OK):

works as expected, login screen waits indefinitely for user to login.

- Reboot (not OK):

Expected: the autologin-user is logged in.

Happens really: the autologin-user seems to be logged in, at least correct backgound and starter is visible, then after a second the login screen is shown again, no automatic login happens further.

Here is the content of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=igor
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=lightdm-autologin
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```